# How to replace some values in multidimentional array with another array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I try to replace some value in a multidimensional array with another array with the same key 
**but it turns out to replace all values**

Here is my example array

```
[
    {
        "book_id": 45,
        "language_code": "RUWT-EN",
        "book_name": Study,
        "country": "Singapore",
        "created_by": 12,
        "created_date": "2019-04-09 09:19:24",
        "update_by": 12,
        "update_date": "2019-06-25 03:57:52",
        "status": "1",
    },
    {
        "book_id": 46,
        "language_code": "RUWT-EN",
        "book_name": Sleep,
        "country": "Indonesia",
        "created_by": 12,
        "created_date": "2019-04-09 09:19:24",
        "update_by": 12,
        "update_date": "2019-06-25 03:57:52",
        "status": "1",
    },
    {
        "book_id": 47,
        "language_code": "RUWT-EN",
        "book_name": Teaching,
        "country": "China",
        "created_by": 12,
        "created_date": "2019-04-09 09:19:24",
        "update_by": 12,
        "update_date": "2019-06-25 03:57:52",
        "status": "1",
    },
]
```

and this is my 2nd array

```
[
    {
        "book_id": 45,
        "language_code": "RUWT-CH",
        "book_name": Study in CH,
        "country": "Korea",
        "status": "2",
    },
    {
        "book_id": 46,
        "language_code": "RUWT-CH",
        "book_name": Sleep in CH,
        "country": "US",
        "status": "2",
    },
    {
        "book_id": 47,
        "language_code": "RUWT-CH",
        "book_name": Teaching in CH,
        "country": "England",
        "status": "2",
    },
]
```

I've tried using laravel map collection and foreach one by one values then replace the value that have the same key, but it was to long . i want 
easiest way

```
$result = $collect_real->map(function($item) use($lang){
              return $item['book_name'] = $lang->where('book_id', $item['book_id'])->values();
            });
```

i want result like this

```
[
    {
        "book_id": 45,
        "language_code": "RUWT-CH",
        "book_name": Study in CH,
        "country": "Korea",
        "created_by": 12,
        "created_date": "2019-04-09 09:19:24",
        "update_by": 12,
        "update_date": "2019-06-25 03:57:52",
        "status": "2",
    },
    {
        "book_id": 46,
        "language_code": "RUWT-CH",
        "book_name": Sleep in CH,
        "country": "US",
        "created_by": 12,
        "created_date": "2019-04-09 09:19:24",
        "update_by": 12,
        "update_date": "2019-06-25 03:57:52",
        "status": "2",
    },
    {
        "book_id": 47,
        "language_code": "RUWT-CH",
        "book_name": Teaching in CH,
        "country": "England",
        "created_by": 12,
        "created_date": "2019-04-09 09:19:24",
        "update_by": 12,
        "update_date": "2019-06-25 03:57:52",
        "status": "2",
    },
]
```

Comment: I do not understand what's your problem. Does your code work or not?

Comment: You have all records with same book id.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro it doesnt work, i want to replace the some value in the 1st array with the 2nd array

Comment: @DrakulaPredatorم ive edit it thank you

Comment: What is your actual behaviour. What's going wrong?

Comment: This is not an ultra clear [mcve]. The coding attempt references `book_id`, but because the 3 rows in both arrays are coincidentally related by their first  level keys.  This means that the accepted answer works with the sample data, but may fail in other realistic scenarios.  `array_replace_recursive()` is concise, but is not relating data by `book_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [array_replace_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) solves your problem in one line of code:

> From the docs:
>
> **array_replace_recursive()** replaces the values of array1 with the same values from all the following arrays. If a key from the first array exists in the second array, its value will be replaced by the value from the second array. If the key exists in the second array, and not the first, it will be created in the first array. If a key only exists in the first array, it will be left as is. If several arrays are passed for replacement, they will be processed in order, the later array overwriting the previous values.
>
> **array_replace_recursive() is recursive**: it will recurse into arrays and apply the same process to the inner value.

Example:

```
$updatedBooks = array_replace_recursive($wrongBooksArray, $correctBooksArray);
```

Comment: This approach merges the row data based on the first level indexes.  It does not relate rows based on the shared `book_id` values.